# Legend text is cut off in mermaid.js diagram generated by Kroki API

Tags: pie-chart, diagram, mermaid

It looks like this for at least most of pie charts:

[image: pie charts]

To make the legend fit into the image, I've tried to change diagram options (e.g. font size) according to [this guide](https://docs.kroki.io/kroki/setup/diagram-options/#_mermaid), but the only option I was able to change is theme.

I've tried all the cases like `?(font-size=8|pie_font-size=8|fontSize=8|pie.fontSize=8)`

Mermaid.js config:

```
pie
"Product Launches" : 3
"Market Recognition" : 2
"Company Strategy" : 1
```

Generated image:

https://kroki.io/mermaid/png/eNoryEzlUgooyk8pTS5R8EkszUvOSC1WUrBSMOZS8k0syk4tUQhKTc5Pz8ssyczPA0kYcSk55-cWJOZVKgSXFCWWpKZXgoQNuQCgcxe6?theme=forest&font-size=8